# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16d8d7ff8)

Tags: swift, xib

I created a PieChart with a own class for the UIView and inside this class the loadNib() method throws this error.

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    let view: UIView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PieChartView", owner: self, options: nil)!.first as! UIView // Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    addSubview(view)
}
```

Comment: `Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PieChartView", owner: self, options: nil)!.first as! UIView`, there is 2 crash possible. First one because `Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PieChartView", owner: self, options: nil)` is nil. Second one, because `Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PieChartView", owner: self, options: nil)!.first` is not a UIView. Which one is it? Separate into two lines, we'll see.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know a more specific diagnosis just by looking at this snippet of code, but I've run into something similar when using `XIBs`. The problem occurred when I tried to define a `Custom Class` within the `Identity Inspector` for my nib's `View`, instead of the `File's Owner`.

Make sure that only your `File's Owner` has a custom class defined in your xib within the `Identity Inspector`. Below, there are two screenshots depicting how you xib should be configured:

[File's Owner configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R257G.png) <- Make sure your custom class **IS** set here

[View's configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXlOK.png) <- Make sure custom class **IS NOT** set here

I am still not sure why, but somehow when defining a custom class for your view instead of the file owner, the view keeps recursively calling its own `init` method multiple times inside the `Bundle.main.loadNibNamed()` method.

My `MusicRowView.xib` file only contains 4 outlet connections, and one of them it's the superview (contentView). The `File's Owner` is set to my `MusicRowView.swift`, and this is how the swift file looks like:

```swift
class MusicRowView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var coverImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var subtitleLabel: UILabel!
    
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MusicRowView", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.addSubview(self.contentView)
        self.contentView.frame = self.bounds
    }
}
```